# Low performance on PostGIS Spatial Query

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, psycopg2

I have a spatial query that find all points inside polygon like this:

```py
startpolygon = time.time()
pointInpolygonV2 = """SELECT col.vessel_hash,ST_X(col.the_geom) AS long, ST_Y(col.the_geom) AS lat, ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326; POLYGON((-28.828125 65.0721301,-28.125 64.7741253,-139.5703125 -47.0401821, 127.265625 -44.5904672,90 71.1877539,-28.828125 65.0721301))'),ST_GeomFromEWKT(col.the_geom))  FROM samplecol As col;"""
cursor.execute(pointInpolygonV2)
pointsINpol = cursor.fetchall()
endpolygon = time.time()
print (CGREYTIME+ "Time to fetch all points inside a polygon: "+CENDTIME), endpolygon - startpolygon
```

The table is in the form:

```
vessel_hash  | status | station | speed |  latitude   |  longitude  | course | heading |        timestamp         |                      the_geom                      
--------------+--------+---------+-------+-------------+-------------+--------+---------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
‎103079215239 | 99     | 841     | 55    | 36.‎14622100 | -5.‎44244810 | 6      | 511     | 2016-07-28T05:55:31.000Z | 0101000020E610000098B55E1D11C515C0847EA65EB7124240

‎103079215239 | 99     | 841     | 45    | 36.‎14238000 | -5.‎44235280 | 355    | 511     | 2016-07-28T05:52:32.000Z | 0101000020E6100000162DE521F8C415C060CD018239124240
```

Also I have an index on field `the_geom`:

```sql
CREATE INDEX samplecol_the_geom_gist ON samplecol USING gist (the_geom );
```

The create table is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE samplecol
(
vessel_hash serial NOT NULL,
status character varying(50),
station character varying(50),
speed character varying(10),
latitude numeric(12,8),
longitude numeric(12,8),
course character varying(50),
heading character varying(50),
timestamp character varying(50),
the_geom geometry,
CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_the_geom CHECK (st_ndims(the_geom) = 2),
CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_geom CHECK (geometrytype(the_geom) = 
'POINT'::text OR the_geom IS NULL),
CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_the_geom CHECK (st_srid(the_geom) = 4326) );
```

‎ 
The problem is that the query is too slow. The response time to fetch `745.902` points is 700 seconds. I have observed that postgis is much faster than mongo with the use of an index. And in mongo the repsonse time for the same query is 90 seconds. Does anyone know how can improve this query or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JGH it seems that the response time is smaller but this is not solve my problem. I figure out that the index `gist` would used if I add `ST_Contains` in `where`. So my query is now:

```
SELECT vessel_hash,ST_X(the_geom) AS long, ST_Y(the_geom) AS lat from samplecol where ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326; POLYGON((17.2045898 37.3002753,17.2045898 37.2827946,17.0947266 35.5143431, 19.8413086 35.6215819,19.8193359 37.2827946,17.2045898 37.3002753))'),the_geom);
```

and the response time is about 20 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The query is likely not using the index, because you are not using the geometry column but a derivation of it.

To use the index, don't use `ST_GeomFromEWKT(col.the_geom)` but directly `col.the_geom`

```sql
SELECT col.vessel_hash,
       ST_X(col.the_geom) AS long, 
       ST_Y(col.the_geom) AS lat, 
       ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326; POLYGON((-28.828125 65.0721301,-28.125 64.7741253,-139.5703125 -47.0401821, 127.265625 -44.5904672,90 71.1877539,-28.828125 65.0721301))'),
          col.the_geom) 
FROM samplecol As col;
```

Comment: I will try this and I will inform you. Thank you for your answer

Comment: It seems that the respone time is smaller now. Form 700 seconds now is 500. Is there nothing else to do? I see that postgis (I test many queries) is almost 4 times faster than mongodb when using indexes. Why this behaviour presented in this query? Do you know?